# Mobile device width and height

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

Currently i design a responsive web design. I use fluid design including the media queries for different widths.

I could not able to find different sizes of different gadgets currently available, could any one help giving types of mobile device widths available for samsung, blackberry, htc, Nokia, Amazon, LG, Motorola, MicroMax etc. And also what should be the common width most widely used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of "common" devices and queries...

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: and for a more thorough list.. check out
http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php

Answer (score 1):

Here is another another detailed list, with many specific devices...

http://nmsdvid.com/snippets/#

It's really useful for creating additional responsive queries for the less common device-widths and so on.

Pay attention to the queries though, they are written to target those specific devices, so some use combinations of min/max widths and heights, along with pixel densities to target that specific device (and exclude others).